# nginx to cache the dynamic URL

Tags: iis, caching, nginx

I have a website

www.somesite1.com which gets all its image content from www.somesite2.com

At the moment each time an image is to be displayed we simply use an absolute URL to get it like this

img src="http://www.somesite2.com/event/image.jpg" /

So each time a user goes to www.somesite1.com for content www.somesite2.com gets hammered.
and the nginx is in front of IIS, so  I  want to cache the image on nginx...not always get from IIS.
Please tell me detail.
Thanks very much~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe too late but you can do that with [the proxy module of nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule).

There are plenty of solutions and you didn't give enough details.

One solution is to have a proxy rule on (for example) /site2/ for the www.somesite1.com domain. These rule will forward request to www.somesite2.com.

And your absolute urls pointing to http://www.somesite1.com/site2/foo.png (for example).

Of course, depending of your url schemes, you can set something more elaborate and less visible (than this silly /site2/ rule).